# Angular 7 Component Interaction Design

Tags: angular, router

An angular app has following components:

FirstComponent which is loaded through URL and has FirstId

ChildComponent which is a child of FirstComponent. ChildComponent loads SecondComponent through router.

SecondComponent is loaded through router and has SecondId.

I need to insert a record with FirstId and SecondId if there is a button click in SecondComponent and the SecondComponent is loaded by ChildComponent inside FirstComponent.

What would be the design to achieve this?

Comment: You have `Input()` and `Output()` for parent - child communication as well as a shared services, which can also help you to communicate with non related components. That's all you need to make it working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- URL: `/path-1/:firstId/path-2/:secondId`
- Route Configuration

```
{ 
  path: 'path-1/:firstId', 
  component: FirstComponent, 
  children: [
    { path: 'path-2/:secondId', component: SecondComponent }
  ]
}
```

You would access the `:firstId` and `:secondId` by injecting the `ActivatedRoute` in the `SecondComponent`.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
    const firstId = paramMap.get('firstId')
    const secondId = paramMap.get('secondId');
  })
}
```

For this to work, you need to set the `paramsInheritanceStrategy` in the root RouterModule configuration.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always' })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case the ids are not available through route.

Comment: @TechAgent Then please expand your post with more information and some code. How can we know what's available?